# Facebook Canvas Redirect URL

Tags: java, facebook

We've been using the the java-facebook library for quite some time (a few years), though it appears one reason we're not getting any new users through FB, is that new users are seeing an error, which I understand is because of FB's new (in June) security.

Currently, we have a "simple" Canvas FB app, using FBML, which users can access via:

```
http://apps.facebook.com/$MYAPP
```

The Canvas URL is returning:

```
http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=$APPID&next=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2F$MYAPP&display=page&locale=en_US&return_session=0&fbconnect=0&canvas=1&legacy_return=1&method=permissions.request
```

This URL, for new users (who have not previously authorized our app) comes back with:

```
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: next is not owned by the application.
```

Existing users (who had enabled the app prior to June) are able to access it without any problems.

Our site URL is specified as:

```
http://apps.facebook.com/$MYAPP
```

This error appears to imply that the site URL and the next URL need to be on the same domain, and not on facebook.

I've been able to change the Site URL to be:

```
http://www.OURREALAPP.com/
```

And, the domain to be:

```
OURREALAPP.com
```

And then, was able to change the Canvas URL to return:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=$CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.OURREALAPP.com%2F$URL%2F
```

This works great, the first time.  It prompts for permission, and displays the correct data.  However, if we access it a second time, it doesn't show it in a "Facebook frame", ie, it sends the user directly to the application.

I've also tried modifying the redirect_uri to go to apps.facebook.com/$MYAPP ... but this gives us an error about not owning the URL.

What do we need to do?  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty worthless a year later, but here goes (for an iFrame Canvas app):

In order to auth new users (using the client-side SDKs) you can do one of two things:

1. Re-direct them to a URL that will then re-direct them to a URL of your choosing.
2. Prompt them with a popup dialog using the JS SDK (but only after they click something)

Users who have already authed your app, probably don't need to do either.

Here is the latest authentication docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/

Here is some code that does uses the JS SDK and forwarding to handle the permissions:

```
<script>

    var fb_perms = "email,publish_actions"
    var fb_url = "http://apps.facebook.com/awesome/"

    FB.init({
        appId      : app_id, // App ID
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // login to facebook
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) return alert("user is logged in!")
        var url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" +
            "client_id=" + app_id + "&" +
            "redirect_uri=" + fb_url + "&" +
            "scope=" + fb_perms + "&" +
            "response_type=token"
        top.location.href = url             
    })
</script>
```

Best,